# Is this database lost ? DBData is corrupted. SQLite error code:26, 'file is encrypted or is not a database'

Tags: sqlite, core-data

After copying the file from an external drive to local hard drive, I got this error and I can't anymore open it:

```
CoreData: error: (26) Fatal error.  The database at BDdata is corrupted.  SQLite error code:26, 'file is encrypted or is not a database'

Error: The file couldn’t be opened because it isn’t in the correct format.
```

Is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: How was this file created? How did you copy it?

Comment: Are you forgetting to provide a password in your connection string? That would result in the same error message if the DB was created with a password.

Comment: @TomHarrington It was created with Apple Core Data and it has been manually copied from the operating system

Comment: @zeFrenchy No password... unless.. is it related to user privileges on osx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A likely reason is that you didn't copy the SQLite journal files. With recent versions of iOS and Mac OS X SQLite uses WAL style journaling. When WAL is used there are multiple files-- your primary SQLite file and two others with the same name but with `-wal` and `-shm` added. If you don't copy everything, you don't get a useable SQLite file.

If that's not the case, the file may be corrupt. I don't know why-- what does "manually copied from the operating system" mean? Was the file on iOS or OS X? Did you just drag from one Finder window to another?

If you're planning on copying Core Data store files like this, it's best to change the journal mode back to `DELETE`, which eliminates the need to copy extra files. You'd do this by including the journal mode as one of the options when adding the persistent store:

```
NSMutableDictionary *storeOptions = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[storeOptions setObject:@{ @"journal_mode": @"DELETE" } forKey:NSSQLitePragmasOption];
// Add other options
```

Then use this as the `options` parameter when calling `addPersistentStoreWithType:configuration:URL:options:error:`.

Comment: Hi, what happens if you manually copy a SQLite file, created (with the same app) in Mountain Lion to Mavericks? Are you going to get a corrupted file?

Comment: Only if you miss the journal files, as I said. Or if your copy method (which you still haven't described) somehow corrupts the file.

Comment: If I'm not wrong there are 2 new journal files are different in Mavericks which are not created in Mountain Lion. Can this be the problem?

Comment: There is not method copying the files, I've copied them manually in Finder, from external drive to local hard disk.

Comment: @Patrick yes, there are journal files that need to be copied. That's what I was describing in the first paragraph of my answer.

Comment: But if these journal files are not created by Mountain Lion (the db has been created on it), and they are needed by Mavericks, from where can I get them?